# How to set a vertical and horizontal border at the same time

Tags: floats, border

I'm writing a cover letter and for the template I have everything except I want to add 2 border lines:

- from top left to 2/3 paper height
- from down right to 2/3 paper length

In the code I've already managed to add the vertical border.
How do I add the horizontal one?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{
    total={200mm,297mm},
    top={20mm},
    tmargin={-3.5mm}
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Default header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Default footer rule
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1]{background}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{30,100,200}

\backgroundsetup{
    position=current page.north west,
    color=myblue,
    nodeanchor=north west,
    contents={\rule{10pt}{198mm}}  
}

\begin{document}

    \includegraphics[width=1.5in,trim={7mm 7mm 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}% Your logo here

    \hrulefill

    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{} l @{}}
        \today\\[12pt] % Date
        Email: julian.@
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}

    Dear Admissions Committee% greeting

    \bigskip

    \blindtext[5]

    \vspace{\baselineskip}

    Yours faithfully% Closing text

    \vspace{2\baselineskip}

    Julian


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you please make your question clearer, and add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) if possible? If I understand your question correctly, I think a TikZ overlay picture is appropriate.

Comment: Run `texdoc tcolorbox`

Comment: I've posted the code I have. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\rule` also for the horizontal rule.

I suggest to you, instead of manually set `198mm`, to use `.66\paperheight`, and the analogous for the width `.66\paperwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{
    total={200mm,297mm},
    top={20mm},
    tmargin={-3.5mm}
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Default header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Default footer rule
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1]{background}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{30,100,200}

\backgroundsetup{
    position=current page.north west,
    color=myblue,
    nodeanchor=north west,
    contents={\rule{10pt}{.66\paperheight}\raisebox{-10pt}{\raisebox{.66\paperheight}{\rule{.66\paperwidth}{10pt}}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \includegraphics[width=1.5in,trim={7mm 7mm 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}% Your logo here

    \hrulefill

    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{} l @{}}
        \today\\[12pt] % Date
        Email: julian.@
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}

    Dear Admissions Committee% greeting

    \bigskip

    \blindtext[5]

    \vspace{\baselineskip}

    Yours faithfully% Closing text

    \vspace{2\baselineskip}

    Julian


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you for the very detailed answer!